# Kotlin - Creating consecutive fragments adds the data in the wrong container

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin, android-xml

I have this piece of code:

```
  val fm = supportFragmentManager
  val container = R.id.details

  this@CampusActivity.runOnUiThread(Runnable {

      fm.beginTransaction()
      .add(
          container, 
          DetailCard.newInstance("Contacts", contacts, action.contactCardList)
      ).commit()

      fm.beginTransaction()
      .add(
           container, 
           DetailCard.newInstance("About", about, action.aboutCard)
      ).commit()
  })
```

I am trying to create new instances of Detail Card with different data, on both these lines. 
The data is saved in `contacts` and `about`, as they are Bundles

But instead of filling up the data in two different cards, all the data is loaded into the first card.

I know the problem.

The `DetailCard` is a fragment with a `Linear Layout` with an id as `listItems`. Now the data I send via Bundles, is used to create even newer fragments called `List Item Fragment`, where the data from bundles is finally loaded.

So, in short, List Items are created using the Bundle data and populated in the Detail Card.

However, since I'm calling several instances of Detail Card, all the List Items are loaded in the first Linear layout with the id `listItems`.

I am sure of this because, before I named the Linear Layout as `listItems`, it had the id `container`, which overlapped with another frame layout with and id of `container`. So the linear layout elements, the List Items, were being loaded in the first xml element with the ID `container` not the container I was hoping for...

How, do I load my List Items in the correct `listItems`, which corresponds to the new Instance of the Detail Card?

Comment: what is the behaviour with commitNow()

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA Just checked. Same results.

Comment: weird I don't have an idea what's happening, will try a sample app to see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA I found the solution. I just had to change the ID everytime I need to use the fragment. This has been happening because, The code just places in the XML layout, where it encounter's the ID first. Usually, people shouldn't have this problem, but I was using `Fragment inside Fragment inside Activity` approach. So, my innermost fragments were being loaded in the inner fragment, which on every run were inflating the same layout and therefore had the same xml ID.

Answer (score 2):

Since, I knew that the items were being instantiated into the first xml layout with the same id as the fragments, the easiest solution was to change the id, everytime.

So, I did that. I went inside my `DetailCard`, and before referencing the `listItems` Linear Layout, I changed its ID.

Here is how I did that:

```
lateinit var itemContainer : LinearLayout

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_card, container, false)

        //This below is my Linear Layout
        itemContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.listItems)

        //Since I've already found it, Let's change the ID
        //I choose a random and larger number, so that If I even if 
        //I have a 100 DetailCards, I'll not run out of IDs
        itemContainer.id = Random.nextInt(5000)

        //Now I just use the ID as the container for the fragment manager, inside Details Card
        val container = itemContainer.id
```